# Powershell parse object / string

Tags: powershell, string-manipulation

Learning powershell, trying to find out how to parse the first value from this resultset:

```
IPAddresses
-----------
{10.60.50.40, fe80::5ddf:a8f4:e29c:b66}
```

Normally I would just look it up, however, I don't know if {x, x} is a standard datatype of sorts in `Powershell` land.

Do I have to do rough string parsing, or is there some standard command to extract the first one, such as:

```
... | Select-Object IPAddresses | Select-String [0]
```

(I just made the select string part up. I'm lost.)

Comment: you could try creating a tupple: http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2014/09/02/using-a-tuple-in-powershell.aspx Then you can access them with $var.Item1 or $var.Item2

Comment: Tried that, doesn't seem to parse it. It seems `IPAddresses` the piece of a tuple already, so you can't break it down further than that.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I have so far:

```
... Select-Object IPAddresses | ForEach {$_.IPAddresses}[0]
```

Returns the first one.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
$myResultSet | foreach { $_.IPAddresses[0] }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$myResultSet | Select-Object -First 1 IPAddress
```

Your result set is a collection of some type. The `Select-Object` cmdlet is taking the first item in that collection and then filtering to only the `IPAddress` property which is then displayed.

On my machine the output of the above command looks like this. Yours will likely differ in that the address returned will be different

```
IPAddress                                                                                                              
---------                                                                                                              
fe80::5581:4fbc:fc22:ec79%13
```

You get the table because by default PowerShell puts the output through `Format-Table` to make a nice display.

To access just the IP address itself you can modify the expression slightly:

`$myResultSet.IPAddress|Select-Object -First 1`

or, by using dot notation and an index into the collection you can avoid using `Select-Object` entirely like so:

`$myResultSet[0].IPAddress`

The above refers directly to the `IPAddress` property of the first item in the `$myResultSet` collection, which has an index of zero hence `$myResultSet[0]`

Either of these will return just the IP address itself like so:

`fe80::5581:4fbc:fc22:ec79%13`

Answer (score 0):

First, you don't have to guess what type `IPAddresses` is, you can get it easily like this:

```powershell
$myResultSet[0].IPAddresses.GetType()
```

Probably it will be some sort of [collection (array)](https://www.simple-talk.com/sysadmin/powershell/powershell-one-liners--collections,-hashtables,-arrays-and-strings/), so  you can use `Select-Object` with `ExpandProperty` parameter:

```
$myResultSet | Select-Object -ExpandProperty 'IPAddresses' | Select-Object -First 1
```

Or you can use [property dereference operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28219516/what-is-the-name-of-this-powershell-syntax) and\or index as **Crippledsmurf** suggested